# C++ class with static mutex & racing condition

Tags: c++11

I have this C++ class with static mutex as private member of the class to protect cout in another public function of the class. But when I call object of the class from two threads I get a racing condition. Not sure why ?

```
class ThreadSafePrint
{
  public:
      void myprint(int threadNumber)
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mymutex);
        cout <<"Thread " << threadNumber << endl;
      }
  private:
      static std::mutex mymutex;
};

std::mutex ThreadSafePrint::mymutex;


int main()
{
    ThreadSafePrint obj;

    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    int threadNumber;
    // create 2 threads and pass a number 
    for(int i=0; i<2;++i)
    {
      // threadNumber = 0 for 1st thread
      if(i==0)
      {
          threadNumber = i;
      }
      // threadNumber = 1 for 2nd thread
      if(i==1)
      {
          threadNumber = i;
      }

      workers.push_back(std::thread([&obj,&threadNumber]()
      {
          obj.myprint(threadNumber);
      }));

    }

    // join all threads
    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(),[](std::thread & th)
    {
            th.join();
    });

    return 0;
    }
```

Here are some results:

```
>> ./mythreads
Thread 1
Thread 1
>> ./mythreads
Thread 0
Thread 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You capture a reference to the local variable `threadNumber` in two worker threads, access it in both threads, and mutate it in the main thread without any synchronisation. This is indeed a race condition. Capture by value instead.

```
 workers.push_back(std::thread([&obj, threadNumber]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture `threadNumber` by value, not by reference.

Exchange:

```
workers.push_back(std::thread([&obj,&threadNumber]()
```

by

```
workers.push_back(std::thread([&obj,threadNumber]()
```

Otherwise the variable `threadNumber` will be altered also for the first thread, by the second loop run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class ThreadSafePrint
{
    public:
        void myprint(int threadNumber)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mymutex);
            std::cout <<"Thread " << threadNumber << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        static std::mutex mymutex;
};

std::mutex ThreadSafePrint::mymutex;


int main()
{
    ThreadSafePrint obj;

    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    int threadNumber;
    // create 2 threads and pass a number 
    for(int i=0; i<2;++i)
    {
        // threadNumber = 0 for 1st thread
        if(i==0)
        {
            threadNumber = i;
        }
        // threadNumber = 1 for 2nd thread
        if(i==1)
        {
            threadNumber = i;
        }

        workers.push_back(std::thread([&obj,threadNumber]()
        {
            obj.myprint(threadNumber);
        }));

    }

    // join all threads
    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(),[](std::thread & th)
    {
        th.join();
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your threads, you explicitly ask the compiler to provide the thread with access to the same instance of the variable `threadNumber` that the main function/thread is using.

```
[&threadNumber]
```

Again: this is an explicit share.

Indeed, your code suggests that you might want to better grasp the language before you experiment with threading, this code is very strange:

```
int threadNumber;
// create 2 threads and pass a number 
for(int i=0; i<2;++i)
{
  // threadNumber = 0 for 1st thread
  if(i==0)
  {
      threadNumber = i;
  }
  // threadNumber = 1 for 2nd thread
  if(i==1)
  {
      threadNumber = i;
  }
```

It's unclear why *anyone* would write this instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    workers.push_back(std::thread([&obj, i] () {
      obj.myprint(threadNumber);
    }));
}
```

Even this still has a number of design oddities - why are you passing `obj` by reference? It's an empty class with one *static* member, you could just as easily avoid the capture and write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    workers.emplace_back([] (int threadNumber) {
        ThreadSafePrint obj;
        obj.myprint(threadNumber);
    }, i);  // pass `i` -> `threadNumber`
}
```